# Count the number of times certain words appear in a column

Tags: excel, vba, office365

Im trying to write a vba code to count the number of times the words Juniors, Seniors, Masters, Grand Masters, Great Grand Master and the Total of all  appear in a column.  I need the results pasted in the appropriate Cell on a different Sheet. if you could point me in the right direction on how to do this it would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have prepared some basic code to point you in the right direction. I have implemented it only for the first two words, assuming that the information is stored in the first column. You can simply change the value of the variable column to the appropiate one. Also, this code loops as long as it doesn't find any empty cells.

```
Sub Count()
    Dim Juniors As Integer 'Counts how many times the word Juniors appears
    Dim Seniors As Integer 'Counts how many times the word Seniors appears
    Dim column As Integer 'column with data
    Dim row As Integer 'iterated row
    Dim CellValue As String 'value of the cell iterated
    
    Juniors = 0
    Seniors = 0
    row = 1
    column = 1
    
    
    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(row, column))
        CellValue = Cells(row, column)
        
        If CellValue = "Juniors" Then
            Juniors = Juniors + 1
        ElseIf CellValue = "Seniors" Then
            Seniors = Seniors + 1
        End If
        
        row = row + 1
    Loop
    
    'Stores the counters
    Cells(1, 4) = "Juniors"
    Cells(1, 5) = Juniors
    Cells(2, 4) = "Seniors"
    Cells(2, 5) = Seniors
    
        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub NameCount()
Dim MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheet2.Range("A1", Sheet2.Range("A1").End(xlDown))

Sheet2.Range("d2").Value = "Junior"
Sheet2.Range("d3").Value = "Seniors"
Sheet2.Range("d4").Value = "Masters"
Sheet2.Range("d5").Value = "Grand Masters"
Sheet2.Range("d6").Value = "Great Grand Master"

Sheet2.Range("e2").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MyRange, MyRange.Find("Junior"))
Sheet2.Range("e3").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MyRange, MyRange.Find("Seniors"))
Sheet2.Range("e4").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MyRange, MyRange.Find("Masters"))
Sheet2.Range("e5").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MyRange, MyRange.Find("Grand Masters"))
Sheet2.Range("e6").Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(MyRange, MyRange.Find("Great Grand Master"))


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Count Values

- Adjust the values in the constants section.
- The second procedure is just a way to populate a column with 'pseudo-random' data.
- If you are not OP, then you can open a new workbook, copy the code into a standard module e.g. `Module1`, and run the second procedure to get the data in `Sheet1` and then run the first procedure to see the result in `Sheet2`.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub countValues()
    
    ' Define constants.
    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const srcFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const srcFirstCellValue As String = "Title"
    Const dstName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const dstFirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const dstFirstTitle As String = "Title"
    Const dstSecondTitle As String = "Count"
    Const dstFooter As String = "Total"
    Const DataList As String = "Juniors,Seniors,Masters,Grand Masters," _
        & "Great Grand Master"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' Workbook containing this code.
    
    ' Define Data Range.
    Dim rng As Range
    With wb.Worksheets(srcName).Range(srcFirstCell)
        ' Define range from first cell to bottom-most cell.
        Set rng = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1)
        ' Define Last Non-Empty Cell.
        Set rng = rng.Find(What:="*", LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        ' Validate Last Non-Empty Cell.
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "No data found.", vbCritical, "No Data"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        ' Define Source Range.
        Set rng = .Resize(rng.Row - .Row + 1)
        Debug.Print rng.Address
        ' Define Data Range (exclude headers).
        Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        Debug.Print rng.Address
    End With
    
    ' Write values from Data List (string) to Data Array.
    Dim Data() As String: Data = Split(DataList, ",")
    Dim DataUpper As Long: DataUpper = UBound(Data)
    
    ' Define Result Array.
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To DataUpper + 3, 1 To 2)
    ' '+ 3' means:
    '     1 - because Data Array is 0 based,
    '     1 - for header,
    '     1 - for footer.
    
    ' Write headers.
    Result(1, 1) = dstFirstTitle
    Result(1, 2) = dstSecondTitle
    ' Write body.
    Dim Tot As Long
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 0 To DataUpper
        Result(2 + n, 1) = Data(n)
        Result(2 + n, 2) = Application.CountIf(rng, Data(n))
        Tot = Tot + Result(2 + n, 2)
    Next n
    ' Write footer (total).
    Result(n + 2, 1) = dstFooter
    Result(n + 2, 2) = Tot
        
    ' Write from Result Array to Result Range (in Destination Worksheet).
    With wb.Worksheets(dstName)
        With .Range(dstFirstCell)
            .Resize(UBound(Result, 1), 2).Value = Result
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub populateSourceWorksheet()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const FirstCell As String = "A1"
    Const FirstCellValue As String = "Title"
    Const DataList As String = "Juniors,Seniors,Masters,Grand Masters," _
        & "Great Grand Master"
    Const PopCount As Long = 100
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim Data() As String: Data = Split(DataList, ",")
    Dim DataUpper As Long: DataUpper = UBound(Data)
    Dim Result As Variant: ReDim Result(1 To PopCount, 1 To 1)
    Dim n As Long
    For n = 1 To PopCount
        Result(n, 1) = Data(Int(Rnd() * (DataUpper + 1)))
        Debug.Print Data(Int(Rnd() * (DataUpper + 1)))
    Next n
    
    With wb.Worksheets(wsName)
        With .Range(FirstCell)
            .Value = FirstCellValue
            .Offset(1).Resize(UBound(Result)).Value = Result
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```